# Value doesn't show up on a DataGridViewComboBox control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

After setting the values in the `DataGridView`, they don't show up on the control even though I can access them through the `Value` property.

The problem is that there is no default `Value` in the `ComboBox` cells.

```
void ComboBoxColumn()
{
    string[] values =  { "one", "two", "three" };
    string columnName = "Test";
    var column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    column.Name = columnName;
    column.ValueType = typeof(string);

    foreach(string item in values)
    {
        column.Items.Add(item);
    }

    Grid.Columns.Add(column);

    // problematic part
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in Grid.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells[columnName].Value = values[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    void SetValues()
    {
        string[] values = { "one", "two", "three" };
        string columnName = "Test";
        var column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        column.Name = columnName;
        column.ValueType = typeof(string);

        foreach (string item in values)
        {
            column.Items.Add(item);
        }

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
    }
```

On my machine this code is running. If I click the ComboBoxColumn I can see the tree values and choose one. What is your problem?

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[columnName].Value = values[1];
        }
```

If you add this code, the default value of the combo box shows the value 'two'.

Comment: That's not the problem, the problem is the second part.

Comment: row.Cells[columnName].Value = values[1]; also works. You didn't provide your code for RandomValue.

Comment: Weird, doesn't work for me. Also, edited the question to make myself more clearer.

Comment: row.Cells[columnName].Value = values[1]; shows the value 'two' as default value. I don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
    void AddComboColumn()
    {
        string[] values = { "one", "two", "three" };
        string columnName = "Test";
        var column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        column.Name = columnName;
        column.ValueType = typeof(string);

        foreach (string item in values)
        {
            column.Items.Add(item);
        }

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[columnName].Value = values[2];
        }
    }
```

These code work too... Check, may be problem in 'RandomValue(values);'?
I haven't this part of code and can't tell for sure.
P.S. In my prog default value == "three".

Comment: I was talking about the default value in the combobox, not the dropdown menu. RandomValues() works fine.

Comment: If I understand You don't have dropdownlist? or You just don't have default value?

Comment: I don't have the default values.

Comment: Funny, I can't repeat this problem. In my way all work great.

Comment: Oh! good! I repeat! I have no default values only if I have column with same Name ("Test"). I call this method 2 times, and in second column I have no default values. Check, may be you have same Column names?

Answer (score 0):

I cant reproduce your error. Here is my 
[sample project](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9JOiSJxT9vjMmQyMjFiN2EtYjdkMi00ZjhjLTgzYzMtYWE2ZTJiZmQxODBj)

Try and give us anything else that might be the issue.

**note**: I copied your code directly (and then added in some rows)

Answer (score 0):

First Make name for combo box in datagridveiw ColDryg 
then in initvalue function write this code

```
  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ColDryg =
 (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)Gv_dtails.Columns["ColDryg"];
             ColDryg.DataSource = db.Drugs.ToList();
             ColDryg.ValueMember = "Id";
             ColDryg.DisplayMember ="Arabic_name";
```

you have table in database its name is Drug